# Reject a string that contains characters other than a-z, A-Z, 0-9

Tags: java, regex

I am unfamiliar with Java's regex, can someone tell me how to determine if a string contains characters other than a-z, A-Z, 0-9?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html)?

Comment: Are you committed to using regular expressions?  Would a simple for loop using `Character.isLetterOrDigit` not be okay?

Comment: what about non ascii letters?

Comment: A for loop of checking for every possible character within the specified range would be faster than a regex? Seriously?

Comment: @AscensionSystems, sure!  You can check for a letter with `'a' <= ch <= 'A'`, etcetera, but a regex needs to get compiled, and then the regex engine has overhead all its own.  A basic loop is almost certainly the fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `[^A-Za-z0-9]` regexp. You can use `\\W`, but that excludes `_` character as well.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
if (p.matcher(stringToMatch).find()) {
    //...
}
```

Detailed information can be found here: [java.util.regex.Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: It is not working properly. If i pass in 'Brian' (without commas) the if statement is skipped...however if I enter 'Brian!' the if statement is still skipped even though it contains an invalid character...What is going wrong?

Comment: @Brian_CS I updated the answer to use `find()` instead of `matches()`.

Comment: @ruakh You are right, thank you! I've been out of Java for 4+ years, and I forgot some nuances of its class library.

Answer (score 1):

Regexes are probably overkill.  If you can use third-party libraries, then using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`CharMatcher`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#CharMatcher):

```
return CharMatcher.JAVA_LETTER_OR_DIGIT.negate().matchesAnyOf(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is Oracle's [Java regex tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

To specifically match a string containing characters *other than* alphanumerical, match `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use matches method from String class:

```
String stringToMatch = "Abc192";
stringToMatch.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]*");
```